# How to clear app data when debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, caching, emulation

I am new to Visual Studio IDE and struggling with a simple problem of clearing app data from the cache when I build a new instance of the app in the debugger and run it. Most emulators like those in android studio and eclipse have a simple way of rebuilding the app from scratch in the emulator so that all previous data gets wiped, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Though still unable to find a way from within Visual Studio to clear the app cache, the app gets installed on the windows machine itself when running from Visual Studio and then remains resident on the computer, thus one can uninstall it from windows itself and this clears the app data so that the next time it is run from Visual Studio, it is a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the menu that allows you to wipe data (like the one you have when using Android Studio instead of visual studio) by clicking on "Open Android Emulator Manager" (you might have to add this as a menu button ), and the selection the virtual device to launch, press "Start" and the dialog box with the option to "Wipe data" appears